# window.location.hash.substring with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a mobile application that runs a jQuery mobile web site through an in-app browser.

When the application starts I attach to the url the phone's  deviceId to keep it in my database.

So the url I load inside the in-app browser looks like this:

> www.myServer.com/doWork.html#deviceIdString

Using JavaScript inside the `doWork.html` file,  I get the `deviceIdString` like this:

```
var userId = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

In jQuery Mobile there is the Single-Page template structure and the Multi-Page template structure. In the latter case the hash symbol `#` is used to navigate between pages. In my project i am using the Single-Page template structure for most of my work.

2 Questions:

1. Since I am using jQuery Mobile is it correct that i use the `#` hash mark to attach things to my URL like the `deviceIdString`? Or should I avoid it? If yes, can I use something else to replace it like a question mark?
2. If I don't use at all the Multi-Page template structure is it safe to use the hash mark `#` for passing information through the URL?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code only, not to highlight random parts of text.

Comment: Thank you. It wasnt random , it was key words for reading faster but probably not a good idea. Thanks for the feedback.